# Why JSON Response accessible in different ways on Javascript response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that searches Data on Soap API

```
$response = $client->getFunctionByIDNumber($args);

        $ndata = $response->return;

        
            if($ndata->errorResponse->errorCode == 64)
            {
                $error = $ndata->errorResponse->errorDescription;
                return $this->fail($error);
            }
            if($ndata->errorResponse->errorCode == 550)
            {
                $error = $ndata->errorResponse->errorDescription;
                return $this->fail($error);
            }
            else{
                $deedsusagemodel->insert($usageData);
                
                return $this->respond($ndata, 200);

            }
```

Everything to this point works perfectly fine.

if i search a user with multiple cars response is in the following format. Accessible in the following way  `response.personInformation.name`

```
{personInformation:{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]}}
```

If the user only has one car

```
{personInformation:{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":[ "Ford"]}}
```

Object is accessible using `response[0].personInformation.name`

Just want to know why am i getting this type of behavior. I want to use javascript and jquery to process the information but because response is different it make it difficult. Any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance

Comment: The response structure is exactly the same in both examples, and can be accessed in exactly the same way. What is the issue you're facing with this structure?

Comment: When i search for a user with 1 car i can access it using response[0].personInformation.name but if the user has more than two cars the response is accessible via response.personInformation.name

Comment: You haven't implemented that behavior in your examples. Please update the examples. As you can see, [`response[0]`](https://jsfiddle.net/xu05h9cf/) throws an error.

Comment: How am i suppose to implement it exactly because I'm getting different response. 

I'm expecting response to be response.errorResponse.errorCode and but now i have to account for both response[0].errorResponse.errorCode

If a user with multiple cars is returned i want to loop through cars. So I'm not sure what you mean by i have not implemented the behavior. So any recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: If you're getting a different response, you're not showing that in the post. Please show the real different responses in the post, currently the data structures are equal. Notice, that if you're getting different responses, then the issue is on the server-side code, and the question has nothing to do with JS.

Comment: Thanks Teemu for your quick responses. Sometimes all we need is guidance in the right direction. I restructured the response by recreating the array. If searched user has car count > 1 then i create a nested array with users personal information and a foreach statement that build the array of cars. This way my response on the view is always consistent